# Is qRegisterMetaType necessary for enum access via typedef in QML?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I found a great example of how to use C++ enums in QML. But I can't seem to figure out why the qRegisterMetaType line is necessary. The following code runs just fine with AND without the following lines:

```
qRegisterMetaType<Status>("Status");
```

and

```
using Status = StatusClass::Value;
```

QML does not throw an error when you leave out those lines. What is the significance of qRegisterMetaType<>() when accesing a C++ enum via a typedef?

statusclass.h:

```
#ifndef STATUSCLASS_H
#define STATUSCLASS_H

#include <QObject>

class StatusClass
{
    Q_GADGET
public:
    enum class Value {
        Null,
        Ready,
        Loading,
        Error
    };
    Q_ENUM(Value)

private:
    explicit StatusClass() {};
};

using Status = StatusClass::Value;

#endif // STATUSCLASS_H
```

main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qRegisterMetaType<Status>("Status");
    qmlRegisterUncreatableType<StatusClass>("qml.guide", 1, 0, "Status", "Not creatable");
}
```

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import qml.guide 1.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log(Status.Loading);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `qRegisterMetaType` function essentially allows a `typedef` or alias to be assigned to a `QVariant`. `QVariants` are important in QML because they used to store the arguments from signals and slots, and also get values from the `QMetaProperty` system.

In the case of this enum, which essentially aliases the `int` type, it will simply mean that the type will shows up as `Status` instead, which is useful for debugging, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to share only enums to QML the **qmlRegisterUncreatableType** is enough.

**qmlRegisterUncreatableType** - This template function registers the C++ type in the QML system with the name qmlName. While the type has a name and a type, it cannot be created, and the given error message will result if creation is attempted. This is useful where the type is only intended for providing attached properties or enum values.

**qRegisterMetaType** - Registers the type name typeName for the type T. Returns the internal ID used by QMetaType. Any class or struct that has a public default constructor, a public copy constructor and a public destructor can be registered. After a type has been registered, you can create and destroy objects of that type dynamically at run-time. This function is useful only for registering an alias, so share objects to QML.

1. https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterUncreatableType
2. https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType